# Can a Union CBA circumvent Right to Work?

Tags: employment, employer, unions

if an employer is in a Right to Work state, Can a union create a contract with an employer that requires the employer only keep union employees on payroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taft-Hartley Act of 1947 banned ["closed shop"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_shop) union agreements in the USA, which is where an employer agrees to only hire union members and only keep union members on the payroll.

So, **no**.

(though there are examples of unions that are effectively closed shop, and the Wikipedia article gives a few examples)